# Is there any way to download questions and answers in a nice format?

Tags: discussion, support, export

I'd love to make a compilation of some questions and answers I've seen here, in the form of a 'short' $\LaTeX$'d pdf.

I know I can just click the edit button and copy the whole question/answer, but I also want to grab directly the author and date, and copying this by hand for 150+ (I'm guessing I'll choose that many) may get tedious.

Does anyone know an easy way/an app to do this?

Also, I believe it's obvious, but I'll add it anyway: I don't plan on making money off this or anything, I just believe there are beautiful answers in this site, and I'd like to do this for myself (and perhaps any user here who's interested).

Thanks!

Comment: Or a newer one: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/15163/save-the-answer-in-pdf/